# Implode array with array of glue strings

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I have a awkward need but I need to interleave an array with another array before imploding the result. I guess my better option would be less talk more example

Array number one

```
[0] => "John has a ", [1] => "and a", [2] => "!"
```

Array number two

```
[0] => 'Slingshot", [1] => "Potato"
```

I need to produce

```
John has a Slingshot and a Potato!
```

My question is can I do that with an implode or I must build my own function?

Comment: [implode does not take 2 array's as argument only a separator and an array so it would not work.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Comment: Dupe of: [Push elements from two arrays in an alternating fashion to form a new flat array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11082461/2943403) + `implode()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Adapted from [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17052755/implode-array-with-array/17053372#comment24656074_17052755) above.*

Are you sure you don't just want string formatting?

```
echo vsprintf("John has a %s and a %s!", array('slingshot', 'potato'));
```

Output:

```
John has a slingshot and a potato!
```

Comment: This answer does not respect the seemingly dynamic arrays provided in the question body.  It is also an antipattern to write `echo vsprintf()` -- if you are going to print it with `echo` then you should more directly just call `vprintf()`.

Answer (score 3):

Simple Solution

```
$a = [0 => "John has a", 1 => "and a", 2 => "!" ];
$b = [0 => "Slingshot", 1 => "Potato"];
vsprintf(implode(" %s ", $a),$b);
```

Use `array_map` before `implode`

```
$a = [0 => "John has a", 1 => "and a", 2 => "!" ];
$b = [0 => "Slingshot", 1 => "Potato"];

$data = [];
foreach(array_map(null, $a, $b) as $part) {
    $data = array_merge($data, $part);
}
echo implode(" ", $data);
```

Another Example :

```
$data = array_reduce(array_map(null, $a, $b), function($a,$b){
    return  array_merge($a, $b);
},array());

echo implode(" ", $data);
```

Both Would output

```
 John has a Slingshot and a Potato !
```

Demos

[Live DEMO 1](https://eval.in/33402)

[Live DEMO 2](https://eval.in/33406)

Answer (score 1):

Might be worth looking at the top answer on [Interleaving multiple arrays into a single array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860490/interleaving-multiple-arrays-into-a-single-array) which seems to be a slightly more general (for n arrays, not 2) version of what otherwise exactly what you're after :-)

Comment: This is Not An Answer -- it is a close vote or a comment at most.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = [0 => "John has a ", 1 => "and a", 2 => "!" ];
$b = [0 => "Slingshot", 1 => "Potato"];

foreach($a AS $k=>$v){
    echo trim($v).' '.trim($b[$k]).' ';
}
```

If you fix your spaces so they're consistent :)

You'd also want to add an isset() check too probably.

Comment: `trim` would be useful here for the space also.

Comment: `$b[$k]` Is not guaranteed to exist.